# Counting numbers in a text file using Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

This has been troubling me for a while now. I normally don't tend to ask help and do my research, but I couldn't find an answer.

How do I write a program that reads a text file, and calculate how many times a certain number shows up?
I'm a huge beginner in Java, and also programming in general. 
Here's my code.

This code generates a text file that has 100 random numbers

```
import java.io.*;

public class Rolling 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int randomNum;

        PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter ("randumnums.txt"));

        for (int i= 0; i < 101; i++)
        {
            randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

            fileout.println (randomNum);
        }
        fileout.close();
    }
}
```

Now the trouble I'm having is that I need to read the file and write a code saying X number was rolled 3 times. e.g the number 4 appeared 5 times in the text file, so I would need it to print "the number 4 was rolled 5 times".

```
import java.io.*;

public class Reading 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("randumnums.txt"));
        int number = 0;
        int inMarks [] = new int [100]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            inMarks [i] = Integer.parseInt(readFile.readLine());
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? are you getting errors?

Comment: Please, format properly your sample code.

Answer (score 4):

You're actually pretty close. It's clear that you're going to have to keep track of your counts in some kind of list, and an array will do quite nicely here.

First, after instantiating `inMarks`, initialize every value in it to 0:

```
int inMarks [] = new int [100]; 

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    inMarks [i] = 0;
}
```

Then change the loop below to this:

```
String nextLine = null;
while ((nextLine = readFile.readLine()) != null)
{
    int thisInt = Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
    inMarks[thisInt] = inMarks[thisInt] + 1;
}
```

`inMarks` now perfectly tracks how many times each distinct `int` was rolled in the file. I'm going to let you implement the print-out part of the assignment, since that will give you a better understanding of how this solution works.

Comment: +1 but you don't have to initialize int arrays, by default they are filled with 0.

Comment: @arynaq: true, but I think it's one of those good habits that makes the code more readable and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling you are looking for something like this (I haven't tested this code)

```
import java.io.*;

public class Reading {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("randumnums.txt"));
        int number = 0;
        int inMarks [] = new int [100]; 
        String readNumber = "";

        while ((readNumber = readFile.readline()) != null) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(readNumber);
            inMarks[number]++;
        }

    }
}
```

The code above basically has an array of 100 integers. We then start reading the file until nothing can be read anymore. Everytime we read a line, we parse into an integer (which normally you should wrap around a try...catch). We then increase by 1 the number of times we have read this number by increasing the corresponding index in the array. So if you want to know how many times the number '32' appeared, you would do System.print.out(inMarks[32]);